# Boundness in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ of the weak limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $p\geq 2$. Let $(u_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ such that $u\in W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ exists so that
$$
u_n\rightharpoonup u \quad\mbox{ in } W_0^{1, p}(\Omega).
$$

I don't know if it is a stupid question or not, but in these hypotheses, we can say that $u$ is bounded in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$? I mean, it is true that there exists $M>0$ such that $\| u\|_{W^{1, p}}\leq M$?

Since $u\in W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$, thus $\| u\|_{W_0^{1, p}}<+\infty$, so I maybe my guess holds. Could anyone please confirm (or not) that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $u \in W^{1,p}$ then necessarily/trivially/whatever $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}< \infty$. So the claim is true with $M:=\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One even have the following: If there exists $M \ge 0$ with $\|u_n\| \le M$, then $\|u\| \le M$.
This follows from the fact that
$$B_M := \{ v \in V | \|v\| \le M\}$$
is convex and closed, thus weakly closed.

(One even has
$$\|u\| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|.$$
)

Comment: One even has: if $\|u\|<+\infty$, there is $M>0$ such that $\|u\|\le M$ :D

Comment: @daw Many thanks!